# Does Slick Direct Embedding with Play 2.0 Work?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-2.0

To spare your eyes and mind from a mountain of source code, I present my use case by word alone.

I am using Slick's direct embedding to pull from a DB.  This works well by itself.

When I try to call the very same methods from a Play 2.0 source, like Application controller, I get a ClassNotFoundException in the browser on refresh.

The class in question is the direct embedded table schema.  Again, everything works when Play is out of the picture.

I have read that direct embedding is still a very experimental feature (although looking at the stable method one has to wonder why they did not just scrap lifted embedding for direct from the beginning) so I think this could be why it is not working.

What does not make sense is that the code I call from Play is not direct to the database source, it passes through another class first.  And the project with database sources is a subproject of the Play project.  Therefore, since there is no direct link, and the class does compile, it should work.

Has anyone experienced this to confirm it will not work?

I am currently switching the code to lifted embedding to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I switched the code to the lifted embedding approach and it worked fine with Play.

Note:

I am ditching Slick in favor of Squeryl for this project (and likely any future projects as well) as I find the lifted approach very anti-DRY and visually unappealing.

There is no reason that in a language as powerful as Scala that lifted embedding should be implemented as it is in Slick.  Add on top of this the spurious import errors, likely being caused by multiple files in Slick packages being named the same, and it creates a sense of dread in using Slick for production.

IMO the current lifted approach should be thrown out entirely, and the embedded approach made the sole subject of future efforts.